# Glmer mixed model with many parameters. Better convergence or more precise estimation?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, convergence

I have a complex model logistic model of the form:

```
cbind(Cases, Pop - Cases) ~ X * log(X) + (X * log(X) | Country)
```

The model has difficulties converging given the low number of parameters and the fact that I have few data for most of the countries.

```
 Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 7.5239 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
```

Nevertheless the model has a better fit (measured by BIC) compared with the same model without interaction.

I noticed that if I set the nAGQ parameter to zero I don't get convergence errors anymore, but I understood that the estimation is less precise.

So, is it better a less precise but convergent fit (nAGQ == 0) or the opposite?

Extra question (a comment answer is ok): how do I interpret the max|grad| in convergence warnings? should it be low or high? What is component 1?